# Custom JSpinner with hours not limited to 24

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

Is there a way to create JSpinner in format hhhh:mm, where hours aren't limited to 24?
for example would be valid to set:
1024:45  (1024 hours 45 minutes)

Comment: Yes, there is.  Just about anything can be represented in a spinner with a custom model.

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13121724/230513).