# JSpinner disallow user to type into it

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

How can I make a JSpinner that doesn't allow manual typing into it. I want my spinner to only have even numbers so I made it increment by twos. The the problem becomes that a user can type say a 3 and now your numbers are 3, 5, 7, 9 all of which are odd. I was hoping I was going to find a method such as `setEditable()` or `setTypable()` but didn't find one. Any ideas?

Comment: I couldn't find an existing answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Create a [`JSpinner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JSpinner.html) that has a custom `DefaultFormatter` and a `SpinnerModel` to which the `JSpinner` does not listen. A complete example is seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13121724/230513).